# How to control react-bootstrap carousel with custom buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

here i need to control carousel slides with custom buttons i achieved this with the help of this [Example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/#controlled).

This is the code for it..

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Carousel, Button, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Cards from "../cards";
import "./slider.css";

const Slider = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };

  const onPrevClick = () => {
    if (index > 0) {
      setIndex(index - 1);
    } else if (index === 0) setIndex(2);
  };
  const onNextClick = () => {
    if (index === 2) {
      setIndex(0);
    } else if (index === 0 || index > 0) setIndex(index + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="button-container">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={onPrevClick}>
              Previous
            </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={onNextClick}>
              Next
            </Button>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        indicators={false}
        controls={false}
      >
        <Carousel.Item>
          <Cards />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <Cards />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <Cards />
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    </>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

But when the active index is in last item that means in the last carousel slide. When i press the next button, it moves all the way around from last carousel to first carousel, i.e the direction is like 3 -> 2 -> 1.

I know that something i made terrible logic in the onClick functions. So i am seeking help to suggest me the best way to control carousel slides with custom buttons , your help is much appreciated. Please review my code and tell me any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

And here is the [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-efs-examples-up5c7?file=/src/components/slider/index.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `ref`  [property](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/carousel/#carousel-props) you can control the `prev` and `next` actions

```
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const onPrevClick = () => {
    ref.current.prev();
  };
  const onNextClick = () => {
    ref.current.next();
  };
```

**JSX**

```
  <Carousel
    ref={ref}
    ...
  >
```